# Specifying a timeframe when scraping from reddit using RedditExtractoR in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, timestamp, reddit

I'm trying to scrape all post titles related to given search-terms from certain subreddits within a given timeframe using R. The package 'RedditExtractoR' is really useful, as I can use this line of code to return all the relevant posts, along with some other useful information:

`> reddit_urls(search_terms = 'immigrant', subreddit = 'ukpolitics', page_threshold = 5, sort_by = "new")`

My problem is, this code returns every post from right now until the page threshold fills, which in this case happens to be a couple of months older than I need, as I set an arbitrary 'page_threshold' while I was testing the code. My time-frame is from the 9th September 2015 to the 23rd June 2016, (the unix timestamps are 1441411201 & 1466726401 respectively, if that is relevant) and consequently I have a couple of months of excess data either side of my time frame.

Is there any way of including some kind argument to restrict the output to a given time-period? such as "since = X", "unitl = X" or "timeframe = X..X"(arguments I've seen in other packages before).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might want a while loop.

Can't install the RedditExtractoR package where I am but it may look something like the pseudo code below:

```
 i <- 1
 min_date <- as.Date("2015/09/09")
 max_date <- as.Date("2017/07/23")

while(Post_min > min_date){

 Data_out <- reddit_urls(search_terms = 'immigrant', subreddit = 'ukpolitics', page_threshold = i, sort_by = "new")

  i <- i+1
  Post_min <- min(Data_out$"column that contains date goes here")
}

 "Cut Data_out manually here using min_date and max_date (filter function, dplyr package)"
```

Edit:
Hi sorry for the late response I was at work on a break before and wasn't install new packages. However I am now at home but expanding on my original code i think the below might help. (That is if you haven't solved it already as it has been a month!)

```
library(RedditExtractoR)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

i <- 1
min_date <- as.Date("2016/01/01")
max_date <- as.Date("2016/09/11")

Post_min <- min_date +1

while(Post_min > min_date){

  Data_out <- reddit_urls(search_terms = 'immigrant', subreddit = 'ukpolitics', page_threshold = i, sort_by = "new") %>%
            mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%d-%m-%y"))


  i <- i+1
  Post_min <- min(Data_out$date)
}

Data_out %<>% filter(date >=min_date  & date <=max_date)
```

Comment: I feel like this is so so close to what I'm looking for, but my understanding of all this is really rudimentary and I'm not quite following what you mean at the end there. Would it help if I included the code or results of the function since you can't get the package where you are? I feel like I should be using
'Data_out$search_date' or something similar, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hopefully the edit above will help. Definitely going to use this package saves wrangling the reddit api!